# Losing session data after POST from third party website

Tags: php, laravel, session, post

I have a Laravel site that redirects to a payment provider (external third party website). When the user completes their payment, they are redirected back to my site via a POST request.

The issue I'm having is that the user's session is lost when they return to the confirmation page.

I wondered if this was behaviour of PHP generally but it seems to be specific to Laravel.

I have checked my sessions.php config file and can confirm the following is set `'expire_on_close' => false,`.

I've created a very basic example of the issue below

**My website (pre-sale)**

Controller

```
public function redirect()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    dd($user); // returns User model;
    redirect()->away('http://www.example.com');

}
```

**Payment provider website**

Note, the request is sent via the application within the browser - not a callback. There is also no button. I just want to demonstrate the POST back to the Laravel site.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

    <form method="POST" action="http://www.example.com/payment/confirmation">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**My website (post-sale)**

Route

```
Route::post('/payment/confirmation', 'Payment\PaymentController@confirmation');
```

Controller

```
public function confirmation()
{

    $user =  Auth::user();
    dd($user); // Returns null

}
```

---

I have added the path to the VerifyCsrfToken middleware's exception array. Is there anything within Laravel that would destroy the session on POSTing via an external website? I'm sure I'm missing something obvious. Thanks

Comment: Please try to track all the requests in a lifecycle using Link Tracer extension and post screenshots of all the redirection.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link-redirect-trace/nnpljppamoaalgkieeciijbcccohlpoh/

Comment: This is likely due to an incorrect SameSite value used when the session cookie was set.

Comment: This was indeed caused by the `same_site` setting in config/session.php. Setting this to null resolves the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by changing `'same_site' => 'lax',` to `'same_site' => null,` in config/session.php. This appears to be a new setting in Laravel 7+.

I'm not sure if there are any security implications caused by this change without further reading but this, for now, fixes the problem. It would be a nice feature to somehow whitelist certain domains.

Answer (score 4):

Setting the 'same_site' => null might not work as expected again because  Standards related to the Cookie SameSite attribute recently changed https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

The new default is now Lax, so if you set your same_site to null, the browser will assume the default of Lax which is not the policy you need.

You need to explicitly set 'same_site' => "none", a value of none for same_site requires your connection to be secure, hence, set 'secure' => true.

```
'same_site' => "none"
'secure' => true
```

Answer (score 1):

In my testing, it seems the session is not actually destroyed. However, it is not loaded when receiving the external POST request, and the session **will be destroyed** if you allow the return to the main site to trigger a new session save. By sending a `header()` redirect and terminating the process before a new session can be saved, it seems that it is possible to restore the existing session.

**Okay, perhaps it's a bit gross?**

```php
Route::match(['get','post'],'/payment/confirmation','Payment\PaymentController@confirmation');
```

```php
public function confirmation(Request $request)
{
    // assert cookie or reload current URL
    if (! $request->hasHeader('Cookie')) {
        header('Location: '.url()->current());
        exit;
    }

    $user = Auth::user();
    dd($user); // user exists!
}
```

I'm not going to say this is a great solution. It does feel a bit hackish. Some additional testing may be required. But at first blush, it does seem to work — at least on my end. And maybe it gives some additional insight into what's actually going on behind the scenes.

Also, I'm not really sure whether you want to expose the payment confirmation page to a GET request.

But this was an interesting rabbit hole to go down for a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to resolve the issue by changing the `same_site` setting in config/session.php

Comment: Interesting. That's a new one for me. I will have to check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep your cookie session to 'lax', you don't want your cookies available on other sites, etc.

The fix as I have found is to pass true for remember when you do a login.

Example:

```php
Auth::login(
   user: $user,
   remember: true
);

$request->session()->regenerate();
```

Your user will now be logged in indefinitely until they log out, ie going away from your site and returning via redirect headers and all that. I discovered this when using Passport to receive a callback for Oauth and I needed to log the user in at that point but redirect them to a subdomain for their tenant.

Normally you'll just want the session to be available across your root domain and subdomains like `.mydomain.com` in your config/env.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, setting Remember on login solved my problem, keeping the default configuration. In my case, my Laravel application received an external post request, and it always destroyed the session of the user who was already logged into the application.