# The user logged out after redirecting from the payment gateway

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have a store website built with laravel 8.x.
When my user went to the payment gateway and redirect to the website(even if the payment succeeded or failed) all sessions cleared, and the user is logged out from their area.

The payment gateway redirect to my website with the `POST` method, I simulate the condition with the `GET` method but it works, but in the `POST` redirection all session was cleared.

I have already added `callback` URL to `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware:

```
protected $except = [
    'logout',
    'callback',
];
```

My callback route is like below:

```
Route::post('/callback', [PaymentController::class, 'callback']);
```

And in the `callback` method user auth is not provided yet:

```
public function callback(Request $request) {
    dd(auth('organ')->check());
}
```

The result was:

```
false
```

Comment: its to do with cookies policy.  The users' browser does not forward the session cookie when the redirect is from a third party.  Please see upvoted answers here (not the one marked correct) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67692358/losing-session-data-after-post-from-third-party-website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is about the SameSite cookie, please read this in [this URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite).

Also remember that where you set the `same_site` attribute to `none`, you must set `secure` to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was `www:` vs `non-www:`

if your callback is `www` and your sign-in URL is `non-www:` Sessions won't work .
You just have to fore `www` to `non-www` in your `.htacccess`

```
#Force www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

#Force non-www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```